# A query to get a JSON element on an object with JMESPATH

Tags: json, filter, jmespath

When I have a simple JSON like:

```json
{
    "name": "Tom",
    "age": 20
}
```

Is there any JMESPath query to get `age` only when `name` is `Tom`?

The query should get `20` with the upper JSON.

But, if the name is not `Tom` like:

```json
{
    "name": "Bob",
    "age": 31
}
```

The query should return `null`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to filter, you will need an array.
And you can get an array from any object with the function [`to_array`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#to-array).

Then, because you have an unique object, you can stop the projection created by the filter, and, take the first element of the array, using `| [0]`, as explained in the [pipe expressions section of the tutorial](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#pipe-expressions).

So with the query:

```
to_array(@)[?name == `Tom`].age | [0]
```

- This will give `20` for the JSON

  ```json
  {
    "name": "Tom",
    "age": 20
  }
  ```
- This will give `null` for the JSON

  ```json
  {
    "name": "Bob",
    "age": 31
  }
  ```