# azure search through images with JMESPath

Tags: azure, jmespath

I'm looking for a way to search through installable virtual machine images for image size.

The `az vm image show` has the following data

```
{
  "architecture": "x64",
  "automaticOsUpgradeProperties": {
    "automaticOsUpgradeSupported": false
  },
  "dataDiskImages": [],
  "disallowed": {
    "vmDiskType": "Unmanaged"
  },
  "extendedLocation": null,
  "features": [
    {
      "name": "SecurityType",
      "value": "TrustedLaunchSupported"
    },
    {
      "name": "IsAcceleratedNetworkSupported",
      "value": "True"
    },
    {
      "name": "DiskControllerTypes",
      "value": "SCSI, NVMe"
    },
    {
      "name": "IsHibernateSupported",
      "value": "True"
    }
  ],
  "hyperVGeneration": "V2",
  "id": "/Subscriptions/c1198d2b-175a-4ed3-acf0-7715e4cd23ac/Providers/Microsoft.Compute/Locations/westus/Publishers/Canonical/ArtifactTypes/VMImage/Offers/0001-com-ubuntu-server-noble-daily/Skus/24_04-daily-lts-gen2/Versions/24.04.202312150",
  "imageDeprecationStatus": {
    "alternativeOption": null,
    "imageState": "ScheduledForDeprecation",
    "scheduledDeprecationTime": "2024-03-22T00:00:00+00:00"
  },
  "location": "westus",
  "name": "24.04.202312150",
  "osDiskImage": {
    "operatingSystem": "Linux",
    "sizeInGb": 30
  },
  "plan": null,
  "tags": null
}
```

What I'm trying to do is

```
az vm image show \
  --urn Canonical:0001-com-ubuntu-server-noble-daily:24_04-daily-lts-gen2:24.04.202312150 \
  --query 'osDiskImage[?sizeInGb <= "40"]' \
  -o json
```

and from there to list all Canonical and other linux distros with osDiskSize < 20.

It's probably between JMESPath lists and structs or similar. I'm using bash/zsh.

Comment: Does `az vm image list` gives you the `osDiskImage` parameter too? If so, could you give a trimmed down example JSON?

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε No, sorry. That's why az vm image show.

Comment: And I guess you cannot pass more than one `urn` to `image show`?

Comment: I skipped this question as every Linux osDiskSize is 32GB in azure. I created my own install image of 4G, and it brought it's own problems with APT and SNAP sizes. https://lev-petrushchak.medium.com/how-to-make-azure-ubuntu-linux-image-less-than-32g-in-size-e6d9a3b5f65f

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're trying to do is fundamentally flawed: `az vm image show` will get the details for a *single* VM image, so it will always return a JSON object (aka a dictionary, see [How to query Azure CLI command output using a JMESPath query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/query-azure-cli?tabs=concepts%2Cbash#dictionary-and-list-cli-results)), and never an array. JMESPath can only natively filter arrays, not objects, so you cannot filter the results returned from `az vm image show` with a JMESPath query.

I think your bet is to use a tool like [jq](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) in a small post-processing script to get the value of the `osDiskImage.sizeInGb` property.

Edit: based on β.εηοιτ.βε's excellent comment you can in fact do this natively through JMESPath using the [to_array](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#to-array) function.

If we issue the following command to Azure CLI:

```bash
az vm image show \
  --urn Canonical:0001-com-ubuntu-server-noble-daily:24_04-daily-lts-gen2:24.04.202312150 \
  --query 'to_array(@)[?osDiskImage.sizeInGb <= `40`] | [0]' \
  -o json
```

This returns the JSON object of the O/S image if the image size in GB is <= 40 GB, otherwise it returns nothing.

Here's a [link](https://play.jmespath.org/?u=4e7ba480-4796-4f52-9bd1-b8e15200c1a4) to a JMESPath playground demoing this.

Comment: You can definitely filter on a single object by casting the object into an array then taking back the first element of the array (since there was only one in the first place)

Comment: Do you reckon I should poll every Canonical/Linux image size separately?

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I don't think you can natively do that in JMESPath though? You'd need to use another tool for that no?

Comment: @simon-pearson you can do it natively; you can have a look here, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/67507302/2123530